# How do I use OR Statement is a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hello i am trying to use an OR statement in a stored procedure but it is not working the way i want it to work...

The first part of the statement is executed perfectly but it seems that what is said after the OR is ignored... I am thinking that their must be another word to use instead of OR?

Hope i don't sound to stupid here..

Here is my stored procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Equipment.EquipmentNo, Equipment.EquipmentDescription AS [Description], Equipment.Barcode, Equipment.SerialNo AS [Serial Number], Equipment.Status
FROM Equipment, AssignEquipment
WHERE (Equipment.Status = 'Open' AND Equipment.Assigned = 'No') OR AssignEquipment.Assigned = 'No'
AND Equipment.EquipmentNo = AssignEquipment.EquipmentNo;
```

Comment: Check your order of operations.  I suspect you want to surround your OR clause with parentheses.

Comment: To elaborate on @RobertHarvey's comment, take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This is not a stored procedure... this is a single query!

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as @RobertHarvey, but then I looked a little closer. How are `Equipment` and `AssignEquipment` related? There probably should be a JOIN in there somewhere.

Comment: Implicit joins are a SQL antip[attern and should not be used. RIght now you havea cross join but whther you intended to have one or not is unclear (part of why you should NEVER use implicit joins, they make bad code such as unintended cross joins possible)

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server AND takes precedence over OR. So what you wrote was the equivalent of:

```
WHERE (Equipment.Status = 'Open' AND Equipment.Assigned = 'No') OR AssignEquipment.Assigned = 'No'
```

If that is what you want then fine, but it is possible you intended:

```
WHERE Equipment.Status = 'Open' AND (Equipment.Assigned = 'No' OR AssignEquipment.Assigned = 'No')
```

You should not mix AND and OR without using parentheses even if the order of operations would be correct because this lets the maintainer of the code know what you intended and that it was not a mistake.

You also have a problem of a cross join which is likely accidental.

So instead of

```
FROM Equipment, AssignEquipment
```

you probably want an inner join or a left join

```
FROM Equipment E
JOIN AssignEquipment AE ON AE.EquipmentNo = E.EquimentNo
```

Or

```
FROM Equipment E
LEFT JOIN AssignEquipment AE ON AE.EquipmentNo = E.EquimentNo
```

Use the first if the records need to be in both tables and the second if you want the records in equiment which do not have a related record in AssignEquiment.

Comment: Thank you for helping me... I am only a second year developer so im new to all of this... my knowledge is therefore still not a great as some... I forgot to join the two tables :( that was the problem... but thank you very much for pointing that out for me!! i appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

the query you have wrotten means condition is

```
 WHERE ( Equipment.Status = 'Open' AND Equipment.Assigned = 'No') OR  AssignEquipment.Assigned = 'No'
```

you need to put condition like this with parenthesis

```
WHERE Equipment.Status = 'Open' AND (Equipment.Assigned = 'No' OR AssignEquipment.Assigned = 'No')
```